# Issue with strpos in PHP

Tags: php, strpos

I have a string that contains the paid modules of a user. If the module is not part of the string, an error page should be shown.

The variable `$paidModules` contains `reminder newsfeed system finance`

This is the PHP part where I check if the user paid for the module. If that is not the case, the `noAccess.php` page should be shown.

```
if($paidModules != null & $paidModules != "" ) {
    if (strpos($paidModules,'reminder') == false) {
        include('noAccess.php'); 
        return;
    }
}
```

The problem is now, even though the variable `$paidModules` contains `reminder`, the `noAccess.php` is shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use empty() instead of != null && != ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/strpos) may return a boolean `false`. It also may return `0` as the position found.

As such you need to use [strict equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
if (strpos($paidModules,'reminder') === false) {
  // code...
}
```

In your case because `reminder` is found in the zero position. Using `==`, PHP type-juggles `0 == false` as *true*.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/strpos)

```
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a 
non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. 
Please read the section on Booleans for more information. 
Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.
```

You want to equate using `===`

```
strpos($paidModules,'reminder') === false
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for exactly false so you don't get string position 0:

`if (strpos($paidModules,'reminder') === false) {`